# Le jeune maquereau printanier porteur d'un message d'amour illégitime de son maître pour une dulcinée : poisson d'avril et autres animaux humains ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire, origine-ou-raison, littérature, zoologie

L'origine du mot [*maquereau*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maquereau/2), le « [poisson](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/maquereau/49304) (scombridé) des mers tempérées, au dos bleu-vert marqué de stries ; moyen néerlandais [*makelâre*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/164451), courtier, de *makeln*, trafiquer» (Larousse), est passablement inusitée : ce serait un emploi au figuré du [maquereau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maquereau/1) *proxénète/entremetteur* parce que ce poisson, « selon une croyance populaire (mais qui ne semble attestée qu'à partir du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, cf. A. Tobler ds *Sitzungsberichte der königlich preussischen Ak. der Wiss.*, 1902, pp. 92-93), [avait] pour rôle de rapprocher les harengs mâles des harengs femelles, qu'il accompagne dans leurs migrations » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/maquereau/2)). D'autres théories (Guiraud) penchent en faveur de familles comme *maquer, macher* et l'idée de taches, etc. En résumé selon la théorie traditionnelle le poisson s'appellerait comme ça parce qu'on aurait pensé, peut-être à tort, qu'il se comportât avec le hareng comme un entremetteur. Vraiment. C'est important parce que le maquereau est aussi une poisson qui *abonde* en [avril](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avril)... :

> La locution *poisson d'avril* ([1466](https://books.google.fr/books?id=2gGKIzkK5UoC&pg=PA351&lpg=PA345&focus=viewport&dq=michault%20%22Biblioth%C3%A8que%20fran%C3%A7oise%22&hl=fr)) a d'abord le sens figuré d'«
>   entremetteur, intermédiaire, jeune garçon chargé de porter les lettres
>   d'amour de son maître », le début du printemps étant propice aux
>   amours illégitimes ; la locution a désigné également un *souteneur*
>   ([1509](https://books.google.com/books?id=53xTGw1T2P8C&dq=%C3%89loy%20Damerval&q=avril#v=onepage&q=poisson&f=false)) d'après un jeu de mots sur le double sens de *maquereau* et
>   parce qu'avril est la saison privilégiée de la pêche au maquereau. Le
>   sens moderne de « plaisanterie, attrape qui se fait traditionnellement
>   le 1er avril » (1691) s'est implanté avec une coutume qui doit
>   remonter au XVIIe s. et commémorer l'ancien échange de cadeaux du
>   nouvel an (quand l'année commençait le 25 mars).
>
> [ Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, sup. A. Rey, ed. Le
>   Robert, à la vedette *poisson*. ]

En effet, avant l'[édit de Roussillon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89dit_de_Roussillon) (édit de Paris de 1564 de Charles IX), en certains endroits du Royaume de [France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jour_de_l%27an#France) le nouvel an était célébré à la date de l'Annonciation (25 mars) et ça pourrait être relié. Il y a plusieurs théories concernant l'origine du [poisson d'avril](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_d%27avril) et des zones d'ombre demeurent...

---

- Hormis le [paresseux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paresseux) ([aï](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%C3%AF/3), [unau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/unau) etc.) connaît-on d'autres noms simples (un seul mot) d'animaux qui sont basés sur des substantifs/adjectifs tributaires d'un comportement humain, comme le maquereau pourrait l'être ?
- L'article Wikipédia concernant le *poisson d'avril* relie le poème de Pierre Michault à la date de 1466 qu'évoque le *DHLF/Rey* pour le sens comportant l'élément du *jeune garçon chargé de porter les lettres d'amour de son maître*. Voici le paragraphe contenant l'expression :

  > Au Seigneur donc convient dire en ce point
  >  Ha Monseigneur je sçay
  >   un adventaige
  >  Moult bel & gent lequel pour ung pourpoint
  >  Je
  >   vous feray amener en partaige
  >  En vérité c'est une droicte
  >   raige
  >  Et si n'y a ne danger ne péril
  >  Mais j'en seray vostre
  >   poisson d Avril
  >  [...]
  >
  > [ Pierre Michault dans Bibliothèque françoise: ou Histoire de la
  >   littérature françoise, chez Pierre-Jean Mariette et Hippolyte-Louis
  >   Guérin, 1745 ]

  Je ne comprends pas ce passage ni ce texte en général. Fait-il mention de quoi que ce soit qui nous fasse croire qu'il s'agisse d'un jeune garçon [...] dont il est question ici ? Ou est-ce de notoriété en littérature à l'époque que ce rôle de l'enfant comme d'un messager et le cas échéant peut-on illustrer ?
- Dispose-t-on de nouvelles informations plus précises/claires sur l'origine du *poisson d'avril* pour désigner la coutume de la plaisanterie du 1er avril ; connaît-on la référence de l'attestation de 1691 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### La référence de 1466

Un extrait plus long de ce texte cité comme exemple de *poisson d’avril* utilisé pour entremetteur, ici entre une dame et un homme marié qui doit échapper aux investigations de sa légitime:

> Flattez doncques Seigneurs & Serviteurs ,
>   Flattez Dames , & flattez Demoiſelles ,
>   Tirez à vous ces haulx & nobles cueurs
>   Par vos doulces vocatives cautelles ;
>   Puis recitez ſouvent doulces nouvelles ,
>   Et au beſoing faictes les toutes neufves
>   En allégant en ce ſubtilles preuves.
>
> Au Seigneur donc convient dire en ce point ,
>   Ha Monſeigneur, je ſçay un adventaige
>   Moult bel & gent , lequel pour ung pourpoint
>   Je vous feray amener en partaige ;
>   En vérité c’eſt une droicte raige ,
>   Et ſi n’y a ne danger , ne péril ,
>   Mais j’en feray voſtre poiſſon d’Avril.
>
> Puis fault venir à la Dame & luy dire ,
>   Ha , Madame , Monſeigneur a des gens
>   Les plus maulvais qu’on ſçeuſt au monde eſlire ,
>   Qui à tous maulx ſont prompts & diligens ,
>   Et font venir toutes les nuys céans
>   Sottes femmes , de quoy moult me deſplaiſt ;
>   Mais je n’oſe de ce tenir long plait.
>
> Et toutesfois , bien ſouvent je remonſtre
>   A Monſeigneur , ſans luy plumer chaſtaignes ;
>   Le mal qu’il fait ; car c’eſt ung let encontre
>   De vous changer pour ces laides araignes :
>   Lors il me diſt , regarde que tu gaignes ,
>   De ceſt an cy n’auras pourpoint , ne robe ,
>   Et dit encores partout que le deſrobe.
>   ——
>   **Je tente une modernisation du texte, sans garantie**
>   *(J’ai opté pour la lisibilité, mais sacrifié plusieurs rimes)*
>
> Donc, flattez seigneurs et serviteurs,
>   Flattez les dames, flattez les demoiselles,
>   Tirez à vous ces hauts et nobles cœurs
>   Par vos douces roueries vocatives¹;
>   Et rapportez souvent douces nouvelles,
>   Au besoin réinventez-les
>   Invoquant pour ceci de subtiles preuves.
>
> Au Seigneur donc il convient de dire:
>   Ha Monseigneur, je connais un avantage
>   Très joli et aimable, lequel pour un pourpoint
>   Je vous ferai conduire en partage;
>   En vérité c’est un besoin légitime,
>   Et aussi, il n’y a ni danger ni péril,
>   Au contraire: j’en ferai votre poisson d’avril.
>
> Puis il faut venir à la Dame et lui dire:
>   Ha Madame, Monseigneur a des gens
>   Les plus mauvais qu’on sut au monde élire,
>   Qui à tous les maux sont prompts et diligents,
>   Et qui font venir toutes les nuits ici dedans
>   De sottes femmes, ce qui me déplaît beaucoup;
>   Mais je n’ose à ce propos tenir un long plaidoyer.
>
> Et toutefois, bien souvent je remontre
>   À Monseigneur, sans lui plumer châtaigne²,
>   Le mal qu’il fait; car c’est un triste heur
>   De vous échanger pour ces laides araignes;
>   Alors il me dit: Regarde ce que tu gagnes³,
>   De cet an-ci tu n’auras pourpoint ni robe,
>   Et il dit encore partout que je le dérobe.
>
> *¹ On désigne ici le cas grammatical du vocatif, utilisé pour apostropher quelqu’un.*
>   *² Sans faire de chichi, directement.*
>   *³ Je comprends cette apostrophe comme une invitation à regarder à ses dépenses, à suivre un budget serré, parce qu’il n’y aura pas de petits cadeaux cette année. Il est possible que je fasse erreur.*

Je comprends bien qu’il s’agit ici d’un encouragement à intriguer à gauche et à droite, à échafauder des rencontres de Monseigneur avec de gentes dames, ce dont on tire bénéfice de lui, puis à vendre l’information à Madame et à doubler les profits. Par contre, l’utilisation de **poisson d’avril** en ce texte en est justement pour moi la partie la plus obscure. L’expression renvoie clairement à **en**, qui le précède de peu, mais trouver à quoi ce *en* réfère m’est plus difficile.

Est-ce à l’*adventaige moult bel & gent*? Est-ce à la *droicte raige* (comprendre ici quelque chose approchant *légitime désir*)? Ou à la satisfaction (non explicitement mentionnée) de cette *droicte raige*?

- Dans le premier cas, le poisson d’avril serait la maîtresse et non l’entremetteur. Cette interprétation n’est sans doute pas retenue car elle ne tient pas le coup contre d’autres attestations, mais en elle-même, elle me semblerait tout de même cohérente.
- Dans le second cas, le poisson d’avril pourrait en effet désigner la personne permettant au sexe du Seigneur de se retrouver en l’endroit où il pourra assouvir son désir. Ça me semble assez grossier comme invitation, et j’ai peine à penser que l’on pouvait ainsi vanter ses capacités à son Seigneur, mais ne dit-on pas aussi «Autres temps, autres mœurs»?
- Finalement, le troisième cas indiquerait bien que le poisson d’avril est un facilitateur d’intrigues domestiques, l’interprétation apparemment retenue. Elle se bute au fait que cette intrigue n’a pas été explicitement nommée, simplement sous-entendue. Mais je peux aussi mal percevoir un certain style d’expression qui était peut-être courant à cette époque et ne l’est plus aujourd’hui (du moins chez moi...).

J’ai aussi trouvé [cet article intéressant](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&collapsing=disabled&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22Resurrection%20de%20Jenin%20Landore%22%29%20and%20%28subgallica%20all%20%22poisson%22%29%20and%20arkPress%20all%20%22cb344172122_date%22&rk=42918;4)  datant de 1892, où l’on tente de séparer le grain de l’ivraie en ce qui concerne l’origine du poisson d’avril. Quelques références à écrits anciens et une volonté de ne pas accepter les yeux fermés ce qui n’est pas solidement défendable.

---

### La référence de 1691

La voici: [La Vie de Charles V, duc de Lorraine et de Bar](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Jean_de_Labrune_La_Vie_de_Charles_V_duc_de_Lorrain?id=MDTtxWJDEvEC).

Au début du texte (pages 16 et suivantes, *poisson d’avril* en 16 & 18), on y décrit un artifice dont usa le Duc François de Lorraine pour s’évader avec sa nouvelle épouse d’une chambre gardée dans laquelle ils avaient été isolés.

La coutume du poisson d’avril au premier jour de ce mois était courante en Lorraine, mais peu connue des Français, qui se méfiaient en ce jour de tout ce qui leur était dit en Lorraine. Le duc fit courir le bruit de leur fuite et réussit ainsi à tromper les Français, qui refusèrent trop longtemps de croire ce bruit et qui ne prirent pas même le soin de vérifier immédiatement sa véracité. Le duc et son épouse firent telle diligence dans leur fuite qu’ils purent atteindre la Bourgogne avant leurs poursuivants et y trouver refuge.

Comment: J’avais répondu au premier point via un wiki, espérant que tout un chacun puisse compléter la liste au fur et à mesure de leurs trouvailles. Je prends néanmoins à mon compte cette réponse aux points 2 et 3 de la question originale.

Answer (score 4):

#### Liste d’animaux dont la dénomination est inspirée de particularités humaines

**Bernard(-)l’(h)ermite:** Crustacé dont la dénomination inclut *ermite* par référence au fait qu'il se retire dans des coquillages abandonnés, sa carapace molle ne le protégeant pas suffisamment. On lui donne le prénom *Bernard*, qui est usité pour désigner d’autres animaux. On le nomme aussi *pagure*.

**Cafard:** Présumé issu de l’arabe *kâfir* «faux-dévot, infidèle», car la blatte est noire et fuit la lumière. L’image revient par la suite à l’humain avec Baudelaire, qui dans *La destruction*, l’une de ses *Fleurs du mal*, propose une tournure qui frappera l’imaginaire collectif:

> Parfois il prend, sachant mon grand amour de l’Art,
>   La forme de la plus séduisante des femmes,
>   Et, sous de spécieux prétextes de **cafard**,
>   Accoutume ma lèvre à des philtres infâmes.

**Capucin:** Singe nommé d’après les capucins, membres de l’ordre religieux des Frères mineurs capucins, dont l’image archétypale inclut une barbe bien évidente.

**Cardinal:** Oiseau dont la couleur rouge rappelle l’habit des cardinaux de l’Église catholique.

**Faucon pèlerin** ou seulement **Pèlerin:** Oiseau de proie qui était [capturé](https://books.google.ca/books?id=IrcZEZ1bOJsC&pg=PA365&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) par les fauconniers lors de son périple, son «pèlerinage», vers les aires de reproduction, et non directement au nid comme d’autres types d’oiseaux similaires, les nids étant généralement en des endroits très difficiles d’accès, cachés sur des falaises.

**Glouton:** Un autre nom du *carcajou*, qui indique sans ambiguïté son féroce appétit.

**Jaseurs:** Oiseaux dont le chant en petits cris rapides et continus ressemble à une conversation.

**Manchot:** Mathurin Jacques Brisson a nommé ainsi cet oiseau *«à cause de la briéveté de leurs ailes»*, par comparaison à un humain auquel il manque (au moins) un bras (ou parfois une main).

**Mante religieuse:** Insecte carnassier dont les membres antérieurs sont habituellement joints comme en une prière.

**Mouette rieuse:** Nommée d’après son cri qui semble indiquer que le rire n’est pas le propre de l’homme. Si la mouette rieuse rit, l’une d’entre elles, apprivoisée par *Gaston Lagaffe*, aura aussi beaucoup fait rire, bien qu’elle fut elle-même d’un caractère assez morne.

**Oviraptor:** Dinosaure dont le premier fossile fut retrouvé près d’œufs qui furent pris pour ceux d’une autre espèce, d’où le nom signifiant en latin *«voleur d’œufs»*. On croit aujourd’hui que le spécimen retrouvé couvait son propre nid, et que le nom fut injustement attribué. Un peu comme les *maquereaux* de la question initiale...

Answer (score 1):

Pour tes noms d'animaux, me viennent à l'esprit...

- Du côté des mammifères, pas grand chose d'intéressant. ***Lamantin*** est ce qui se rapproche le plus.
- Du côté des oiseaux, la récolte est plus intéressante:

  - ***Jaseur*** et ***moqueur***, pour commencer.
  - ***Chevalier*** et ***vacher***, bien entendu.
  - Et puis ***Bruant***, qui n'est étymologiquement qu'une autre forme de *bruyant*.
- Pour les insectes, j'inclurais le ***monarque*** et la ***tordeuse***

Comment: Le **raton laveur** serait-il valide? Il se tient du moins assez près de la ligne de démarcation. Pareil pour le **bernard-l’hermite**...

Comment: Du côté de l’église et de la vie monastique, il y aurait le **capucin**, le **cardinal**, la **mante religieuse**, ainsi que quelques moines: le **phoque moine**, la **grue moine**, le **vautour moine**, le **loriot moine**.